# rewrite HTTP verbs

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I have a REST api that is invoked by a Javascript Web application.
HTML/CSS and JS files are stored locally and served by Apache, and the REST api is invoked with a ProxyPass directive by Apache on a remote HTTP server.
This is my actual httpd.conf file (development machine is on windows):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myapp.com
    DocumentRoot C:\myapp

    <Directory />
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    RewriteLog C:\Temp\rewrite.log
    RewriteLogLevel 0
    RewriteEngine On

    # Let apache serve static files
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f
    RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]

    ProxyPass / http://192.168.0.23:4567/ retry=0
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.0.23:4567/
    ProxyPreserveHost on
</VirtualHost>
```

My problem is that the remote server (192.168.0.23) does not support DELETE and PUT requests (I get a Method not allowed error if I try to do that).
Unfortunately i don't have access to that server, but I can develop the REST api exposed by it.
What I would like to do is

- check if the incoming request is DELETE or PUT
- set an HTTP header on the request X-ORIGINAL-REQUEST_METHOD: DELETE
- forward the request to the remote server (192.168.0.23) as POST

can this somehow be done with Apache rewrite rules or some other module?

Comment: That sounds like an ugly hack.  Having those methods working is kinda a must for a REST API - is it blocking them intentionally?  What HTTP server software is it running?

Comment: Yes, it's an ugly hack I know, but as a workaround it should work, if I can get it working that way. The HTTP server software is the "Oracle Embedded PL/SQL Gateway".